# General/Dynamic type as a parameter C/C++

Tags: c++

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
class Test {
    Test() {}
    Test(generalObject a){
       // do something
    }
}

int main(){
    Test a = 5;
    Test b = "A";
    Test c = true;
}
```

Is this even possible with the solution I would like?

`generalObject` can be any other type as well, doesn't need to be class type. Of course I know that I can write like different operator for different type, but I would like to skip that phase.

Comment: `operator::=` is not kinda valid. It should be `operator=`

Comment: Yeah, right, sry I"m out of touch in programming in C langs :/

Comment: C or C++? Chose one, they are quite different.

Comment: Give your class a member of type `boost::any`  (or some other variant, e.g. MS C++ comes with one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These:

```
Test a = 5;
Test b = "A";
Test c = true;
Test d = Test();
```

are not assignments, they are [copy initializations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). Compiler looks for a non-explicit constructor (including copy constructor for the last statement). `operator=` is not needed in your code.

As you're not doing anything with the passed arguments, this comes up (only to get your code to compile):

```
struct Test {
    Test() = default;

    template <typename T> // a constructor template
    Test(T const&) {}
};
```

C++ does not have a base class for every type, you need to use constructor template to instantiate a constructor for every type that's required - at compile time.

---

This gets more complicated if you actually want to store the argument inside `Test` (template specializations for array types, convenience function template `make_test`, etc...). I guess this is your entry to templates, so you might want to go step by step.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it as well ^^fixed it

Answer (score 1):

In you example you dont need assignment operator, but [converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) which will accept various types:

```
class Test{
public:    
    Test(){}

    Test(int r){}
    Test(const char* r){}
    Test(bool r){}
    Test(const Test& r){}
};
int main(){
    Test a = 5;
    Test b = "A";
    Test c = true;
    Test d = Test();
}
```

But it makes sense to implement also assignment operator. If you really need any type then use templates, your constructor will look like below:

```
    template<typename T>
    Test(const T& t){}
```